# In Terraria, is it possible to completely reclaim a Corrupted area?

Tags: terraria

Well, what I tried to do was completely cleanse a Corruption area. I assumed it's all about the grass, since that seems to be how the Corruption spreads, and other biomes (such as the Underground Jungle) work like that.

So, I bought a few stacks of Purification Powder and Sunflowers, and purified every bit of Corrupted grass I could find.

It didn't completely work, however. Slimes/Zombies now spawn, but so do Eaters of Souls, still — and the music hasn't changed.

Is there something else that has to be done to completely eradicate the Corruption? (I've already smashed every single Shadow Orb; I doubled checked using the World Viewer.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The Eaters of Souls spawn when Ebonstone is present.  You need to mine or purify all of that.

Comment: Oh. Well, that makes sense and is really annoying. Screw getting rid of the Corruption then, there's tons of the stuff...

Comment: you need quite a bit of ebonstone in close proximity, though, so move on as soon as the music stops and don’t hunt down every single piece.

Comment: Good point.  You don't need to mine/purify all the Ebonstone.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this a lot faster with Dynamite. ;)

Comment: True, but in this case "faster" means "still a lot more time than I'm willing to invest, given how effective [my current solution](http://cloud.steampowered.com/ugc/577798892362649169/A6C2E41D5C35BF2658D89F1E3BEE9DB5723F38EF/) already is". Also, expensive.

Comment: @lunboks: You are still left with the monsters that spawn above, so it's more efficient to remove the upper half of the chasms with dynamite... ;)